# "converting temperature from f into c" not working in def

Tags: python

Problem: Convert

> f=c9/5 +32

using def function.

I have tried this:

```py
def calculator ():
    c=input("write celcius")
    f=int(c)*9/5+32
    return f

print(calculator)
```

> PS F:> python .\q.py    function calculator at 0x030F0810

Comment: `print(calculator())`

Comment: As mentioned above, print(function), what you do is actually print this function object, not calling this function

Comment: To actually explain what's going on in @Roshan's answer, `calculator` on its own is the name of a function. It acts very similar to a variable: you can use it in a function (`print(calculator)`), assign things to it (`calculator = 23`), or anything else. It's just a name. So when you tell Python to `print(calculator)`, it prints whatever `calculator` currently points to, in this case a function, along with the address in memory where the function lives. If you want to tell Python to actually *run* that function, you add `()` at the end to run it, just like with `print()`, e.g. `calculator()`.

Comment: @MichaelKolber Well and nice explaination :)

Answer (score 2):

Since calculator is a function, not a variable you should use `print(calculator())`. Also you should fix the indentation of your return statement. A return statement should be inside the function block.
This should work

```
def calculator ():
    c=input("write celcius")
    f=int(c)*9/5+32
    return f

print(calculator())
```

Comment: Add an explanation to help OP understand their problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is an indentation error in your code. You should add the return statement inside the function.

And also add parenthesis `()` to the function where ever you are calling the function.

The solution :

```py
def calculator ():
    c=input("write celcius")
    f=int(c)*9/5+32
    return f

print(calculator())
```

Comment: The indentation problem is only in the post. Otherwise, OP wouldn't have got the result that's showed in the post.